# Proof $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k}{n-k} = f_{n+1}$ where $f_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci-number

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

In our combinatorics script it is written, that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k}{n-k} = f_{n+1}$$ where $f_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci-number.

Apparently this can be proven through the generating function

$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{k}{n-k}$$

I've looked on stackexchange math and on the internet, but I couldn't find a proof.

I know that $$\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k=f_{n+1}$$

and it can be proven through this

$$\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n+1-k}k=\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}{k-1}=
\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-1-(k-1)}{k-1}=
\sum_{k\ge0} \binom{n-k}k + \sum_{j\ge0} \binom{n-1-j}{j}= f_{n+1}+f_n = f_{n+2}.$$

But I don't know how its done for the first case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
A(x)
&= \sum_{n\ge 0} x^n\sum_{k\ge 0} \binom{k}{n-k}
\\&= \sum_{k\ge 0} \sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{k}{n-k}x^n
\\&= \sum_{k\ge 0} x^k\sum_{n\ge k} \binom{k}{n-k}x^{n-k}
\\&= \sum_{k\ge 0} x^k\sum_{n\ge 0} \binom{k}{n}x^{n}
\\&= \sum_{k\ge 0} x^k(1+x)^k
\\&= \frac1{1-(x+x^2)}
\end{align}
All that remains is to recall $\sum_{n\ge 0} f_nx^n=\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how you get to (1+x)^k?

Comment: @NotEinstein Use the binomial theorem. See edit for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Both $\binom{k}{n - k}$ and $\binom{n - k}{k}$ are only non-zero if $0 \le k \le n$ (so the sums are finite). The sum $\sum_{k} \binom{n-k}k$ can be written as

$$ \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n - 1}{1} + \binom{n - 2}{2} + \cdots + \binom{n - n}{n}. $$

If you reverse the order (which corresponds to the involution $k \leftrightarrow n - k$), you get

$$ \binom{0}{n} + \binom{1}{n - 1} + \binom{2}{n-2} + \cdots + \binom{n}{n-n},$$

which is the sum $\sum_k \binom{k}{n-k}$.

Comment: $\dbinom{n-k}{k}$ can be nonzero when $k$ is larger than $n$. This is a major annoyance and every combinatorialist has stumbled at least one across it.

Comment: @Darij I'm not seeing it. Are you possibly thinking of a different but similar looking quantity? Combinatorially, $F_n$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of ones and twos and $\binom{n - k}{k}$ is the number of ways with $n - 2k$ ones and $k$ twos. Certainly you can't have more than $n/2$ twos.

Comment: The combinatorial interpretation requires the "numerator" to be nonnegative, while $\dbinom{x}{k} := \dfrac{x\left(x-1\right)\cdots\left(x-k+1\right)}{k!}$ gives nonzero values for negative $x$.

Comment: @Darij I see that, but the sum in the question doesn't make sense if you allow those values. In this context, it is necessary to require $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ unless $n \ge 0$ and $0 \le k \le n$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg There are two equally valid generalizations of $\binom{n}k$ to real $n,k$. One is $$\binom{n}k=\begin{cases}(n)_k/k! & k\in \mathbb N\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ This is the generalization where $\binom{n}k$ can be zero when $k\ge 0$ but $n$ is negative. The other generalization is $$\binom{n}k=\begin{cases}(n)_{n-k}/(n-k)! & n-k\in \mathbb N\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ For this generalization, you do have that $\sum_{k}\binom{n-k}{k}$ is a finite sum equal to $F_{n+1}$. This works even for negative $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Extensions