# Is it possible to derive the identity $F_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$ from the generating function $F(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x-x^2)}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

if $F_{n+1}$ is the the $n+1$th Fibonacci number, is it possible to derive the identity

$F_{n+1} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$

by using the generating function $F(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x-x^2)}$?

The only way that I could think of doing this was maybe by showing that

$\frac{F^{(n+1)}(0)}{(n+1)!} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$

and I was able to derive the following expression for the $n$th derivative of $F(x)$,

$\frac{F^{(n)}(x)}{n!} = \frac{x^{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}F_k\binom{n+1}{n-k}x^{n-k}}{(1-x-x^2)^{n+1}}$

Which will give us $\frac{F^{(n+1)}(0)}{(n+1)!} = F_{n+1}$, but not the binomial sum expression. Is there any way to demonstrating that the coefficient of $x^0$ in the above expression is equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n-k}{k}$? Or any other way of deriving the same from the generating function?

Comment: Yes, I show how to do that in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3086382/177399). You already know that $F(x)=x/(1-x-x^2)=\sum_{n\ge 0} F_nx^n$. Next, define $A(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$, where $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-k}k$. Through algebraic manipulation, I show that $A(x)=x/(1-x-x^2)=F(x)$, which proves that $a_n=F_n$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: That's a really neat way of showing it, thank you!